# Creating objects with random attributes

Tags: java

I'm building a railway simulator including the classes Passenger and Station (among others). The Passenger class has an attribute endLoc, which will be the desired end location for each passenger (i.e. a station object). I'm generating a random number of passengers at each station on my network into an ArrayList, and would like their attribute of endLoc to be randomly generated as well (out of a list of all the station objects), but I can't work out how to make the attribute be a random one from a list each time.

```
    ArrayList<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
    for (int i = 0; i<p; i++){
        passengers.add(new Passenger(statA));
```

i.e. Once I have my random number, and have it mapped to which station I want, what do I put in the code instead of statA, to mean the station that applies to my random number?

Can anyone tell me how to do this, or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the type of randomness you're after. Do you want a pseudo randomness such that the number of times each station is selected as an end point is equal, or do you want some stations to be preferred over others (simulating hubs), or some other type of randomness?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain very well. I know how to generate the random numbers I want and match them to my stations, I just don't know what to put in as the endLoc when I create the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write something like this:

```
    List<String> stations = new ArrayList<String>();  
            //add stations..in the list

    int numStations = stations.size();

    int maxPassengersAtStation = 100;//assgin you number

    for(int sCount=0; sCount<numStations; sCount++){
        int passangersAtStation = (int)(Math.random() * maxPassengersAtStation);
        for(int j=0; j<passangersAtStation; j++){
            int passengerDestination = sCount + (int)(
                       Math.random() * ((numStations - sCount) + 1));
            passengers.add(new Passenger(stations.get(passengerDestination)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I can use a .get in the attribute passing, I didn't realise that! Thanks, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some random ideea would be to generate a number from 1 to your_list.length and then take that object from the list and assing it to your endLoc.

Comment: The problem I'm having is how to I tell the program to pass an unknown object to the endLoc?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random int x and then do x = x % allStations.size(); 
The x would be your random index of the list with all stations.